# Getting the mean & sd out of a logistic regression model using GLM

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

Using the set of data below and using R in Rstudio im attempting to form a very simple logistic regression model using "glm" and then given the formula `logit ProbOfBreastFeed = a + b * Age` where `a is the intercept` and `b is the slope` im trying to get the mean and standard deviation of a and b. Im new to R so perhaps its a misunderstanding here in how to get to this but when attempting to use glm im getting the error `Error in model.frame.default(formula = logisticBabies ~ No + Yes * Age,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'logisticBabies'` and im not quite sure why that is or how to resolve that. Any insight?

**DATA**

```
Age   No    Yes
28     4     2
29     3     2
30     2     7
31     2     7
32     4     16
33     1     14
```

**Current R Code**

```
glm(logisticBabies ~ No + Yes * Age, data = logisticBabies, family = binomial)
```

Comment: The first argument is the formula argument and you are passing `data` (`logisticBabies`) to it. See `?glm`.

Comment: ahhhh okay so should the formula of a + b * Age go there instead then? A example if possible would be great, im on the man page but even for glm.fit the two variables would be Age = X and No + Yes = Y but that seems to return an error as well

Answer (score 1):

```
logisticBabies <- structure(list(Age = 28:33, No = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L), Yes = c(2L, 
2L, 7L, 7L, 16L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

What you want is:

```
fit <- glm(cbind(Yes, No) ~ Age, family = binomial, logisticBabies)
```

and then for the parameter estimates:

```
summary(fit)
#Call:
#glm(formula = cbind(Yes, No) ~ Age, family = binomial, data = d)
#
#Deviance Residuals: 
#      1        2        3        4        5        6  
#-0.1472  -0.4602   0.8779   0.1114  -0.6119   0.3251  
#
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
#(Intercept) -16.7198     6.0630  -2.758  0.00582 **
#Age           0.5769     0.1977   2.918  0.00352 **
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#
#    Null deviance: 11.1772  on 5  degrees of freedom
#Residual deviance:  1.4968  on 4  degrees of freedom
#AIC: 19.556
#
#Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```